# Call out other macros

Tags: excel, vba, call

I have a macro I am constructing and I would like to call out different procedures present in the same macro sheet. Please try to solve it providing me the code, the order and the specific definition of the macro.
Example:

```
Sub MyUserName()
dim UserName as String

UserName = "Alessio_110"
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub msgbox_1()
msgbox UserName
End Sub
```

In this example I would like to have a message box telling me the User Name I have set in a precedent procedure. How could I embed the two codes?

Comment: Read this http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Scope.aspx Move your declaration of `UserName` outside the sub.

Comment: "Please try to solve it providing me the code, the order and the specific definition of the macro." - **GImmee the codez**?

Comment: se also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367662/how-can-i-keep-the-value-of-this-variable-for-my-next-subroutine/11367962#11367962 (the first example I could find)

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16374253/how-to-make-excel-vba-variables-available-to-multiple-macros/16374516#16374516

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Excel VBA variables available to multiple macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16374253/how-to-make-excel-vba-variables-available-to-multiple-macros)

Answer (score 0):

To call a procedure you can just use its name. You pass the data as an argument to the called procedure:

So

```
    Sub MyUserName()
    dim UserName as String

    UserName = "Alessio_110"
    MyCalledProc UserName  'calles MyCalledProc and passes UserName as a reference
    End Sub

    Sub MyCalledProc(UserName as String)
        MsgBox UserName
    End Sub
```